# How to catch single and double click on a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a mastercheckbox in my jqgrid columnb header. The requirement is like on single click one pop up has to be shown and if I double click on the same mastercheck box, I have to display another pop up. I am new to jquery,javascripts and I am in confusion whether I can catch both single and double click events on same checkbox. Also if I have to double click, just after I clicked one time, my single click event will be called right? Can you give some idea how to do this? And as of now I haven't started coding for double click (Also I don't know how to catch double click event).

Comment: i think you use change event and check it is checked or not :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  $('#checkbox1').on('click',function() {

    });

  $('#checkbox1').on('dblclick',function() {

    });
```

//dunno whether dblclick triggers for checkbox...
//better use change event

Answer (score 1):

```
     $('#checkbox1').on('change',function() {

    if($(this).is(":checked"))// behave like  click
    {
// do your stuff
    }else{// behave like double-  click
// do your stuff    
}

        });
```

reference **[change](http://api.jquery.com/change/)**

**[:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)**

**[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)**

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/WnwSn/2/)**

Comment: Can you pls set a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: sure i will set @Sanjay wait 5 min

Comment: thank u. I can't go for a double click directly right? I mean  without showing alert("click"); , I can't directly go for alert("doubleclick"); by anyway right?

Comment: in checkbox and radio box click and double click not possible this is done with change  i think you change your input type if you want with click and double click

Comment: Sorry for troubling you but I didn't understood change input type with click and double click.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39239/discussion-between-sanjay-and-rituraj-ratan)