# onclick and ondblclick not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jqgrid, onclick

I have a mastercheckbox in my jqgrid header

```
<input type="checkbox" id="masterCheckBox"  ondblclick="onDoubleClick(event,assetSearchResults,this)" onclick="masterCheckBoxChecked(event,assetSearchResults,this)"/>
```

When I put only onclick or ondblclick, corresponding method is getting called. But when I have both onclick and ondblclick, only onclick method will be called. I can't even double click the checkbox. How to handle both onclick and ondblclick for single checkbox?

Below are the methods for singleclick and doubleclick. I have given timeout also. But I am unable to catch doubleclick event.

```
var timer=;

    function onDoubleClick(e,table,obj){
            clearTimeout(timer);
            alert('Double click');
            }

            function masterCheckBoxChecked(e,table,obj){
                 document.getElementById("masterCheckBox").checked=true;

                 if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
                 timer = setTimeout(function() { alert('Single'); }, 150);   
                 alert(timer);

                 }
```

Comment: if you want it then follow to 'Unobtrusive javascript'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373994/how-to-catch-single-and-double-click-on-a-checkbox/19374061#comment28711138_19374061

Comment: @Jai. Can you explain me bit more in detail?

Comment: @Riturajratan. That question I only asked but that solution is not working.

Comment: but you can set your logic with "change" in check-box click and doubleclick not a good logic dear :)

Comment: okay but why click and dblclick you want both at same time.

Comment: @Riturajratan. Yeah I agree. But there, everytime, before going to doubleclick event, singleclick event is getting called and then we are proceeding. I want doubleclick event to be called directly without invoking singleclick event.

Comment: Double-clicking a checkbox is not standard GUI behaviour. I would find an alternative if possible (extra button?).

Comment: @Jai. On singleclick I have to execute a different logic and on doubleclick I need to execute another logic. I don't want both at same time. But it should be defined for same checkbox. Based on no of clicks, corresponding call should happen.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie. No extra buttons..:-( I could do that with richmodelpanel. But the requirement is like double click on a checkbox is required.

Comment: @Sanjay let me explain when you click on checkboc then it state is checked ok that at that time you do nothing and when you click again then it unchecked then do your stuff]

Comment: @Riturajratan. Problem is I have a pop up for both single and double click. So when I have to doubleclick the checkbox, before I could check it for 2nd time, singleclick pop up will appear.

Comment: then set a variable and open popup by this variable like 

if you click set it 1 and check variable value  if ===1 then open popup first and when click again it will incrment by 1 then check if===2 then show second popup  and then reset variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick ref:

> It is inadvisable to bind handlers to both the click and dblclick
>   events for the same element. The sequence of events triggered varies
>   from browser to browser, with some receiving two click events before
>   the dblclick and others only one. Double-click sensitivity (maximum
>   time between clicks that is detected as a double click) can vary by
>   operating system and browser, and is often user-configurable.

jQuery reference: http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

So I think it's better if you reconsider your actual UI using only one click event and other controls to handle your needs; eg on the click handler open a menu with the possible actions.